# How to plot the field of values of a matrix

Tags: plotting, linear-algebra

For a given matrix A (let's say of dimension 2 to keep it simple), I need to plot in the complex plane its field of values.

The field of values of a matrix is defined as the set $\{\langle{Ax, x}\rangle \mid x \in \mathbb {C}^n, \|x\|=1 \}$ (the brackets represent the dot product).

I tried doing it with the `ContourPlot` function but I don't know how to use it for vector functions. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Since you are already considering complex-valued vectors, in the $2\times 2$ case, you already need four dimensions to visualize the manifold.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {{1, 4}, {6, 4}};
ContourPlot[{x, y}.a.{x, y} == 0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

or

```
a = {{2, 4}, {6, 4}};
RegionPlot[{x, y}.a.{x, y} < 0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```